# pagination gets This webpage is not available

Tags: channel, pagination, get

I am totally lost.

So pagination is something i have used many times except this time it gives an "This webpage is not available" ?

i stripped down everything to the minimum and this is the code

**EDIT**
    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" }

### {title}

```
    {paginate}
    <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
  {/paginate}

 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

If i remove {pagination} it works perfect, the moment i add pagination it's all gone!

What is it that i'm doing wrong?

Extra module that i have added lately is the publisher , but i'm not sure that is even related.

Comment: Have you tried using the paginate= tag?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't do anything

Comment: No worries, Visual. Couple of things: have you turned on your template debugger and in your browser (web inspector or alike) have you checked for any js errors + can you see any html the pagination tags are supposed to parse?

Also what do you mean by: "If i remove {pagination} it works perfect" - do you mean the {paginate} pair tags or just the {pagination_links}tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding paginate="bottom" parameter.

```
     {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" paginate="bottom"}
        {paginate}
           <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
        {/paginate}
     {/exp:channel:entries}
```